# PHP Fatal error: Class 'sfConfig' not found in while run PHP Excel Symfony1.4

Tags: php, excel, symfony-1.4

i am trying to run basic example of phpExcel in symfony1.4 and i am getting this error

```
C:\wamp\www\orangehrm-3.01\symfony>php plugins/sfPhpExcelPlugin/examples_1_2/01s
imple.php
10:39:01 Create new PHPExcel object
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'sfConfig' not found in C:\wamp\www\orangehrm-3.01\symfo
ny\plugins\sfPhpExcelPlugin\lib\sfPhpExcel.class.php on line 9
```

any idea will be approciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for this plugin's examples is a bit strange. It uses the `sfConfig` class to read Symfony config variables but doesn't initialize nor include any Symfony code (hence the error).

In fact when you look at the code of this plugin you'll see that all it does is set some configuration when instantiating `PHPExcel` object. I would skip the plugin altogether and just use the `PHPExcel` directly in your project (you can either include it in the controller where you use it or in the `ProjectConfiguration.class.php` to make it available for the whole project (not recommended though).

Comment: can you show how to use PHPExcel directly to my project step wise,because i am new with this framework, and i dont know you to do

Comment: Just use the examples which are on the PHPExcel's website. If you generate the `xls` in your controller you can `require_once sfConfig::get('sf_lib_dir').'/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';` and then use it as in the example (I'm assuming that you keep the PHPExcel code in `lib/PHPExcel`).